# Listing objects in ArrayList in GUI and alternating between many ArrayLists

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jframe, jlist

I'm currently working on a personal project, in this project, the user is asked to create objects under 3 different categories, so after the object is created, there's a method that check's the category of the object and then it adds it to an ArrayList.
More Details: the object is called Vehicle, there're three categories: Two wheels, three weels, three wheels. So, when you create a new Vehicle, you'd be asked to specify what kind of vehicles you're creating, say you said two wheels, a method will be called which will add the object into ArrayList twoWheelList, and so on.

I have two problems at the moment, I'm making a GUI for this program, where I'd like to display information stored in the ArrayLists, basically the user has a comboBox, which has the name of the three categories underneath it. I'd like that when the user chooses let's say "Two Wheels", a jList will list each object in the ArrayList twoWheelList

How can I make that happen? I've tried several times but I'm coming out with no luck. I'm using NetBeans, I don't really understand the whole JFrame concept and how to write the source codes, for the first problem where I'd need the program to know what did the user choose, should I just use an IF statement? 
How can I make the ArrayList of objects to be displayed in the jList?

Comment: Right, to understand the whole concept of JFrame and swing you can go and read a tutorial

Comment: When the user selects an item (category) from the combo box, create a new `ListModel` which either wraps or otherwise contains the elements from the `ArrayList` and apply it to the `JList`, which I assume you have on the screen...

Answer (score 1):

Start by adding an `ItemListener` to the `JComboBox`.  In the `itemStateChanged` event, you will want to monitor the `ItemEvent` or the `SELECTED` state.

Get the selected value from the `JComboBox`.  This may require you to provide some kind of look that can associate the item in the combo box with the `ArrayList` or, as I would prefer, a wrapper class which contained the name of the item an the `ArrayList` wrapped into a single object, which would provide the means to obtain the `ArrayList`

Then using a custom `ListModel`, you can wrap the `ArrayList` within it and apply it to the `JList` you have on the screen...

```
public class ProxyListModel extends AbstractListModel<Vehicle> {

    private List<Vehicle> vehicles;

    public ProxyListModel(List<Vehicle> vehicles) {
        // It might be better to simply make a copy of the list
        // but that's up to you...
        this.vehicles = vehicles;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        return vehicles.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Vehicle getElementAt(int index) {
        return vehicles.get(index);
    }

}
```

Check out [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) and [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more details.  Play close attention to the discussions about custom rendering.