# Retrieving filename from Jfilechooser into JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist, jfilechooser

I'm having some problems with my class that I need some help with. The class is supposed to take retrieve a csv.file from the file chooser, and then put the name of the file into a Jlist, but I can't get the JList to print the arraylist that I put the chosen files into. This is the code I've got, so I'd be grateful if you could take a look at it and tell me what I need to change with it in order to get the JList to print the arraylist.

```
import dao.UserDAO;
import db.DemoDB;
import model.Activity;
import model.DataPoint;
import model.Statistics;

public class LoginGUI1 {
    DemoDB DemoDBSingleton = null;

    private JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    UserDAO userDao = new UserDAO();
    JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Välkommen till din app");
    JFrame f = new JFrame("User Login");
    JLabel l = new JLabel("Användarnamn:");
    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Lösenord:");
    JTextField textfieldUsername = new JTextField(10);
    JPasswordField textfieldPassword = new JPasswordField(10);
    JButton loginButton = new JButton("Logga In");
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
    JList listAct = new JList();
    List<Activity> activityList = new ArrayList<Activity>();
    List activityList1 = new Vector();

    JFrame jf;
    JMenu menu;
    JMenuItem importMenu, exitMenu;


    Activity activity = new Activity();



    public LoginGUI1() throws IOException {



        DemoDBSingleton = DemoDB.getInstance();
        ProgramMainFrame();

    }


    private void ProgramMainFrame() throws IOException {

        mainFrame.setSize(800, 600);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.setJMenuBar(mb);
        mainFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());;

        tabbedPane.add("Dina Aktiviteter", createViewActPanel());
        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        tabbedPane.add("Diagram för vald aktivitet", createViewDiagramPanel());
        tabbedPane.add("Statistik för vald aktivitet", createViewStatisticsPanel());
        tabbedPane.add("Kartbild över vald aktivitet", createViewMapPanel());


        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        menu = new JMenu("Meny");
        importMenu = new JMenuItem("Importera aktivitet");
        importMenu.addActionListener(importActionListener);
        exitMenu = new JMenuItem("Avsluta program");
        exitMenu.addActionListener(exitActionListener);
        menu.add(importMenu);
        menu.add(exitMenu);
        mb.add(menu);
        mainFrame.setJMenuBar(mb);

    /*  JPanel listholder = new JPanel();
        listholder.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("ListPanel"));
        mainFrame.add(listholder);
        listholder.setVisible(true);
        listholder.setSize(500,400);*/



    }

    private JPanel createViewActPanel() {
        JPanel analogM = new JPanel();
        analogM.setBackground(new Color(224, 255, 255));
        return analogM;
    }





    ActionListener importActionListener = new ActionListener() {


        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int returnValue = fc.showOpenDialog(mainFrame);
            if(returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            {
                File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                if(file != null)
                {
                    String fileName = file.getAbsolutePath();
                Activity activity = null;
                try {
                    activity = new Activity();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                    try {
                        activity.csvFileReader(fileName);
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    activityList.add(activity);
                    listAct.setListData(activityList.toArray());

                }

            }
        }

    };




    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new LoginGUI();

    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably just me, but `listAct` hasn't been added to the UI - so I'm not sure how you expect it to update anything.  I'm also scratching my head over your file reading process, but that's probably a comment best left for another time

Comment: To remove all the confusion, consider providing a [mcve]

Comment: I'd also recommend making use of a `ListModel` (and wrapping it around the `ArrayList`) - see [Creating a Model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#creating) for more details

Comment: @MadProgrammer Indeed it is not added. I temp. removed it when I tried running the program but the outputs from the filechooser did not show up in it.

Comment: @p18wisa02, *if I wanted to store the output that you get from choosing the file in an arraylist, and then add the arraylist to the JList, how would I do that?* why? The point of using the `DefaultListModel` is that it manages the data for you. In any case you were already given the answer. You need to create your own `ListModel`. Have you read the `Creating a Model` link provided above yet? Do you have a specific question about what you read?

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of context missing, so the best I can do is provide a simple running example which works.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JList<File> fileList;
        private DefaultListModel<File> fileListModel;

        public TestPane() {
            fileListModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
            fileList = new JList(fileListModel);

            JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");
            addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                    if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(TestPane.this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                        File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                        fileListModel.addElement(file);
                    }
                }
            });

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(new JScrollPane(fileList));
            add(addButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

    }
}
```

I'd highly recommend having a look at [How to use lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) to get a better understanding of how the API works

Comment: Thank you, this was just was I was looking for!

Comment: Just one more question, if I wanted to store the output that you get from choosing the file in an arraylist, and then add the arraylist to the JList, how would I do that?

Comment: Generally, the same way as above - although I might consider making my own `ListModel` backed by the `ArrayList`, but then you'd be responsible for the event handling

Comment: so just replacing the defaultlistmodel with an arraylist? and also, what do you exactly mean by creating your own listmodel backed by your array? do you think you could show it?

Comment: If all else fails, just use the `DefaultListModel`. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23281531/listing-objects-in-arraylist-in-gui-and-alternating-between-many-arraylists/23281834#23281834) would be how you define your own `ListModel`